# Can I make a loop that start from a certain pointer and end where it started?

Tags: c, loops, pointers

I'm trying to construct what resembles the clock policy algorithm.
  Now I need my loop to a perfect clock starting from a pointer and ending at it if it didn't find what it's looking for i.e :-
`for(i=ptr;i<50;i++)`
then if it didn't find what it's looking for it's going to loop from
`( i = 0 ; i < ptr; i++)`
Is there a way to make this logic in one loop?

Comment: No, the next time i need the i to be equal to 0 and loop till i < ptr. for ( i = 0 ; i < ptr ; i++). Like for example i need it to loop on an array from a certain index and if it reached the end of the array and didn't find what it was looking for it's going to start from the start of the array till that index.

Answer (score 3):

Use modular arithmetic in a `do` loop:

```
i = ptr % 50;
do{
    //body of loop
    i = (i+1) % 50;
} while(i != ptr);
```

Comment: I don't think it's the same, if `ptr` is `>=50`, then also your loop body will execute, which seems wrong...

Comment: @SouravGhosh I read the question as wanting to loop over the integers mod 50 with the loop both beginning and ending at a given `ptr` in the range 0 to 49. `i` will never leave that range.

Comment: Right, given the `ptr` resides in the range. What if it does not? `for` handles that, but `do..while` does not. Sorry, can't agree both are same. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I took that as a natural precondition implicit in the problem statement. You do raise a valid concern. I'll tweak the code to enforce the precondition.

Comment: Thanks for getting the point. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with modular arithmetic in loops, is this going to iterate first from the value of the ptr till 50 then from ptr=0 till the original value of ptr?! Like the i enters the loop the first time with the ptr % 50 not ptr...

Comment: When `i` hits `49` the line `i = (i+1) % 50` will cause it to wrap around to 0. From there it will go to 1,2,..., with the loop stopping when it hits `ptr` again.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question, is you want to check for a certain sub range first and if it does not satisfy your condition, then go for rest of the range, which is basically, checking the entire range.

You can get this done in a single loop itself, just change the looping logic a bit. Instead of *starting* from a value and *going up* to the range, start from the higher range to the lower range. This automatically covers the requirement.

Something like

```
for (int i = 50; i > 0; i-- )
```

will do the job. It will combine the effectiveness of two loops, like

- `for ( i=ptr; i < 50; i++)`
- `for ( i=0 ; i < ptr; i++)`

Comment: I'm following a certain algorithm, so it's important for me to start from the ptr then end at it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try some kind of hack using `%`.

The question is, do you want ptr to be hit once or twice?

If only once, the following might suffice.

```
for (i = ptr + 1; i != ptr; i = (i + 1) % 50)
```

If you want the loop to start exactly at ptr, and end exactly at ptr, you'd have to keep some overflow flag to handle it.

To be honest, it might be a better idea to just use two loops. It is way more clear what you try to do, and less error-prone.

Comment: Well, it's like I'm looping an array from a certain index, and if it didn't find what it was looking for from the range starting from that index till the end of the array it's going to start from the start of the array and stop at the index.